# React Native restarts on home button pressed on android

Tags: android, react-native, mobx-react

When I use the app selector and go to another app and return to mine t works well.
This is my App component

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import { SplashScreen } from './screeens/SplashScreen';
import { DashboardScreen } from './screeens/DashboardScreen';
import { AppNavigator, AppNavigatorNoAuth } from './routes';

@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
  @observable isInitialized = false;
  @observable isFontInitialized = false;
  @observable isLoggedIn = false;

  @action
  initializeApp = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isInitialized = true;
    }, 3500)
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.initializeApp();
  };


  render() {
    if (!this.isInitialized) {
      return <SplashScreen />
    } else if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
      return <AppNavigatorNoAuth />
    } else {
      return <AppNavigator />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you handling any action for `BackAndroid`? If so , please post the code.

Comment: No, I don't have any code in the android side

Comment: I think it may be related to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8570#thread-subscription-status I will test proposed solutions when I'm back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation got to this bug report in react-native repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7079
I tried the solution from "rreusser" and it worked.
I added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on my main activity declaration on the manifest.xml